# Xamarin.forms Rg.plugins.Popup as loading indicator

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Rg.plugins.Popup in my xamarin.forms app. I know how to use the plugin as popup. But can I use this as a loading indicator? What I am trying to do is When user clicks a button some API calls are made, at that time I just want show some animations as loading indicator. I know how to create popup with animation. But how can show the pop on button call and hide when the background task end?

For popup showing I am using

```
 PopupNavigation.PushAsync(new Popup());
```

For showing as indicator how should I call and hide this popup?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is, in your ViewModel, in the Method for the Button's Command, Call a asynchronous method to get the data from the API call and store it in a variable and check once the variable is not null, hide the Popup.

```
var result = await SomeAPICallAsync();

if(result != null)
PopupNavigation.PopPopupAsync();
```

Comment: Bro Iam not using mvvm pattern.  How can I Show and hide in page?

Comment: You can try using the above code in Task.Run() method.